# ReferenceError: FullCalendar is not defined

Tags: node.js, fullcalendar

I've been trying to implement fullcalendar now by using the example provided in the docs. When I try to run it, I get this Error:

> ReferenceError: FullCalendar is not defined

I know what this message means, but where and how do I have to define it?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'list', 'googleCalendar' ],
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,listYear'
    },

    displayEventTime: false, // don't show the time column in list view

    googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyDU6o_4vQlJbLRI8Tb3TCnCRGi2GsiB***',

    // US Holidays
    events: 'en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',

    eventClick: function(arg) {

      // opens events in a popup window
      window.open(arg.event.url, '_blank', 'width=700,height=600');

      // prevents current tab from navigating
      arg.jsEvent.preventDefault();
    }

  });

  calendar.render(); });
```

I'm 16 y/o and therefore somewhat unexperienced. So if this question seems too simple, I'm sorry.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you importing the `FullCalendar` lib with the `require` keyword ?

Comment: @LucasGras I am also having the same issue when importing via require('fullcalendar') in app.js in Laravel. However it works fine when using cdn library. Any idea why this does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this at the top

```
declare var FullCalendar: any;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you didn't import the `FullCalendar` source files to make it works. Or the path to the css or js files is wrong. I did it on my side and it works like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />

    <link href='core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />

    <script src='core/main.js'></script>
    <script src='daygrid/main.js'></script>

    <script>

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ]
        });

        calendar.render();
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

My `html` file is located in `fullcalendar/packages` of the **Getting started**, you can find the zip file with all sources here: [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/getting-started#download)

You can still find CDN of FullCalendar on this page: [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/package/fullcalendar) ([cdn example](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@3.10.1/))

Answer (score 1):

Include this in your html, before your script.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.3.0/main.min.js"></script>
```