# FullCalendar is not defined

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, laravel-7

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60081860/referenceerror-fullcalendar-is-not-defined) question but that question couldn't solve my issue.

I am trying to implement fullCalendar in Laravel application. My View file is like below

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('/js/main.js') }}" rel="“application/javascript">
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

                var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    initialDate: '2020-06-12',
                    editable: true,
                    selectable: true,
                    businessHours: true,
                    dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                    events: [
                    {
                        title: 'All Day Event',
                        start: '2020-06-01'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Long Event',
                        start: '2020-06-07',
                        end: '2020-06-10'
                    },
                    {
                        groupId: 999,
                        title: 'Repeating Event',
                        start: '2020-06-09T16:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        groupId: 999,
                        title: 'Repeating Event',
                        start: '2020-06-16T16:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Conference',
                        start: '2020-06-11',
                        end: '2020-06-13'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Meeting',
                        start: '2020-06-12T10:30:00',
                        end: '2020-06-12T12:30:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Lunch',
                        start: '2020-06-12T12:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Meeting',
                        start: '2020-06-12T14:30:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Happy Hour',
                        start: '2020-06-12T17:30:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Dinner',
                        start: '2020-06-12T20:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Birthday Party',
                        start: '2020-06-13T07:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Click for Google',
                        url: 'http://google.com/',
                        start: '2020-06-28'
                    }
                    ]
                });
                    calendar.render();
            });
    </script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 40px 10px;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #calendar {
            max-width: 1100px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am getting `ReferenceError: FullCalendar is not defined` error.

[image]

Comment: Where is your script to load calendar?

Comment: @tmhao2005, `<div id='calendar'></div>` here I am loading the calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the script of `FullCalender` to your markup
this is the cdn for this library https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.2.0/main.min.js

Comment: Thanks @Eslam Adel. Your solution is working. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please help me to implement all these things in Laravel ?