# Uncaught ReferenceError: FullCalendar is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I tried to use FullCalendar , but it gives me error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: FullCalendar is not defined

and also

> error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'datepickerLocale')

I have already tried the solutions:
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60081860/referenceerror-fullcalendar-is-not-defined) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63212778/fullcalendar-is-not-defined) but still the same error.

I don't know how to solve this error.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');


        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            locale: 'fr',
            eventDisplay: 'block',
            firstDay: 1,

            
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            },
            locale: 'fr',
            editable: false,
            droppable: false, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
            eventClick: function (el) {
                el.jsEvent.preventDefault();
                $("#showEventModal").modal('show');
                $("#showEventModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                    $('#loading_zone').hide();
                    $('#target_zone').show();
                });
                $("#target_zone").load(decodeURIComponent( el.event.id));

                console.log($("#target_zone"));
            }
        });

        calendar.render();

    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AGENDA</title>
    <link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="https://findicons.com/files/icons/2805/squareplex/512/google_calendar.png">
    
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootswatch@4.5.2/dist/flatly/bootstrap.min.css"
              crossorigin="anonymous">
        

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
              integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w=="
              crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
        
        <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.13.1/css/all.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"
              integrity="sha512-63+XcK3ZAZFBhAVZ4irKWe9eorFG0qYsy2CaM5Z+F3kUn76ukznN0cp4SArgItSbDFD1RrrWgVMBY9C/2ZoURA=="
              crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js'></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
   
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-GDey37RZAxFkpFeJorEUwNoIbkTwsyC736KNSYucu1WJWFK9qTdzYub8ATxktr6Dwke7nbFaioypzbDOQykoRg=="
            crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
           
</head>
<body>

    <div class="card mb-4 mt-3 p-2">
        <div id='calendar'></div>
    </div>

</body>
 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/locales-all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/locale/fr.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- DATATABLE -->
</html>
```

Comment: N.B. There was no need to repeat your error message multiple times! Once is enough :-)

Comment: You can use this cdn, `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.4/index.global.min.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second locale file won't work because it's for the wrong version of fullCalendar. Only use the file which matches your fullcalendar version.

Also you need to load the main fullCalendar JS file *before* the locale file, because the locale file depends on fullCalendar. Once you correct those two things, it should work.

Summary of changes:

1. Remove `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/locale/fr.min.js"></script>` because it's not needed in fullCalendar 5
2. Move `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/main.js"></script>` before `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/locales-all.min.js"></script>` in the HTML.

Demo:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');


        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            locale: 'fr',
            eventDisplay: 'block',
            firstDay: 1,

            
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            },
            locale: 'fr',
            editable: false,
            droppable: false, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
            eventClick: function (el) {
                el.jsEvent.preventDefault();
                $("#showEventModal").modal('show');
                $("#showEventModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                    $('#loading_zone').hide();
                    $('#target_zone').show();
                });
                $("#target_zone").load(decodeURIComponent( el.event.id));

                console.log($("#target_zone"));
            }
        });

        calendar.render();

    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AGENDA</title>
    <link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="https://findicons.com/files/icons/2805/squareplex/512/google_calendar.png">
    
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootswatch@4.5.2/dist/flatly/bootstrap.min.css"
              crossorigin="anonymous">
        

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
              integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w=="
              crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
        
        <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.13.1/css/all.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"
              integrity="sha512-63+XcK3ZAZFBhAVZ4irKWe9eorFG0qYsy2CaM5Z+F3kUn76ukznN0cp4SArgItSbDFD1RrrWgVMBY9C/2ZoURA=="
              crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js'></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
   
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-GDey37RZAxFkpFeJorEUwNoIbkTwsyC736KNSYucu1WJWFK9qTdzYub8ATxktr6Dwke7nbFaioypzbDOQykoRg=="
            crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
           
</head>
<body>

    <div class="card mb-4 mt-3 p-2">
        <div id='calendar'></div>
    </div>

</body>
 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/locales-all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- DATATABLE -->
</html>
```